Why is the movie titled "Sweet Smell of Success"?
The plot of Sweet Smell of Success (1957) is as follows:

Press agent Sidney Falco is tasked by powerful columnist J.J.
Hunsecker to  break up his sister Susan's relationship with a jazz
musician. Sidney  resorts to unethical tactics, leading to Steve's
career being ruined  and Susan's disillusionment. Realizing the truth,
Susan abandons J.J.  and chooses a new life.

Why is it titled "Sweet Smell of Success"?

I think the point is that success might smell sweet but it has a bitter aftertaste.

Is this watching and not understanding the movie or just not understanding its title? Watch Mean Spirited People Use Others to Climb Up might not make such a good title. The movie is based on the screenwriters real life experience and originally was called Tell Me About It Tomorrow!, but Sweet Smell of Success was his preferred title for it.

@blobbymcblobby - https://i.sstatic.net/EDbtqDZP.png According to David Brown of Cosmo; https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6479406-let-me-entertain-you

@Valorum hehe I know, reminds me of peoples reaction to the word,  moist

I'm also curious as to why it's Sweet Smell Of Success with no leading article; I'd expect The Sweet Smell Of Success.

Hasn't the phrase existed for far longer than the movie?  I know I've heard variants on it, like "The sweet taste of victory, the bitter smell of defeat".  Given the number of possible variants, it might be hard to trace back the first use of such a metaphor, but I suspect it's pretty ancient.

Ernest Lehman uses the phrase twice in the source novelette. In both instances it's very much in the literal sense; 'Cheap' smells bad, 'expensive' smells good.
When he 'hits it big', the narrator expects to be surrounded by nice-smelling things and nice-smelling people.

I walked into the huge, thickly carpeted show place that Hunsecker called a living room, past the statuettes and golfing trophies that stood on the table in silent tribute to the man’s self-love, and I sank exhausted into the green club chair. The lights were dim. The Capehart in the corner was playing softly, and as I sat there gazing at the portrait of Hunsecker on the wall, my eyes slowly closed, and I allowed the soothing music and the muted sounds of the city and the rich, sweet smell of success that permeated the room to lull my senses. I breathed the smell deeply, memorizing the scent, and then all at once I became aware of other sounds, other perfumes, and I turned, startled, as I heard her saying quietly, “You’re early, Sidney.”

And

The sidewalks were steaming and the air was heavy with exhaust fumes, but still it was good to be outside, away from the fetid odors of old newspapers and dirty walls and Gloria’s cheap toilet water. When I got my new office, it would have thick carpeting and rich, bleached oak furniture, and the air would be scented with the sweet smell of success.

Lehman is constantly making reference to how people smell in his books and novels. Generally, for example, you can tell a class of woman by her scent. Whores wear perfume you can buy in 'gallon bottles for a dollar' whereas ladies wear 'delicate scents that intoxicate the senses', etc, etc.

Is it mentioned or referenced in the film?

@RonJohn No, that's for sure.

@ShaneTyson - Nor in the screenplay
